# Show owner name of a file in C

Tags: c, unix, implementation, ls

I'm implementing the ls command and I'm doing the -l option right now. I have some issues with the owner's name. It always print's the id instead of name.

Here is my function:

```
void print_user_ID(char* filepath) {
    struct stat sb;
    struct passwd pwent;  
    struct passwd *pwentp;
    char buf[_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX];

    if(stat(filepath, &sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat"); 
    }

    if (!getpwuid_r(sb.st_uid, &pwent, buf, sizeof(buf), &pwentp))  
        printf("%10s ", pwent.pw_name);  
    else  
        printf("%7d ", sb.st_uid);  
}
```

Do you have any idea where is my mistake?

Comment: if `getpwuid_r()` returns non-zero, you should check `errno` for details

Comment: Change `_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX` to some bigger number.  `_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX` is supposed to be used in `sysconf()` function to get the buffer size.  Also, you should call `getpwuid_r()` only if `stat` succeeds.

Comment: `getpwuid_r()` being re-entrant requires a `malloc`ed memory that can be `realloc`ated. Change pwent to be a pointer, then allocate a memory to it and change pwentp to point to address of pwent. In summary it should look like `getpwuid_r(sb.st_uid, pwent, buf, sizeof(buf), &pwent)` where `pwent` is a pointer with allocated memory.

Answer (score 3):

The comment of Alok SInghal answers my question. I had to change _SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX to a bigger number.

Comment: You might like to accept your own answer, so SO now this question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `getpwuid` or `getgruid` fails, to fix that just do a `itoa` to `st_uid` and it will be fixed :D

Like this:

```
struct passwd   *pw;
struct group    *gr; 
if ((pw = getpwuid(st.st_uid)))
    (!arg->g) ? printf("%s", pw->pw_name) : NULL;
else
    (!arg->g) ? printf("%s", itoa(st.st_uid)) : NULL;
```

Comment: `itoa()` is not portable.  Not only that, the version you've posted is not reentrant while the original question used the reentrant `getpwent_r()`, presumably to provide a reentrant implementation. The original question already handled this properly with `printf()` - `itoa()` is completely superfluous.